# What can I do to get jquery.address working in Opera when using iframe?

Tags: iframe, opera, jquery-address

I have a web page, which heavily uses jquery.address plugin. Now I need to display this page in iframe (social network app). And it works fine in all browsers except Opera (I have Opera 11.62). Here is the error i get:

```
[04/12/2012 01:14:14 AM] JavaScript - 
Inline script thread
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: onhashchange
Error thrown at line 15, column 8 in () in http://vk.autosprite.ru/media/js/jquery.address-1.5.js:
    var _trigger = function(name) {
called from line 13, column 4 in ($) in http://vk.autosprite.ru/media/js/jquery.address-1.5.js:
    $.address = (function () {
called from line 11, column 0 in http://vk.autosprite.ru/media/js/jquery.address-1.5.js:
    (function ($) {
```

Any ideas why this happens and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera forbids accessing top.document properties such as "title" or event "onhashchanged" from IFRAME and throws error "Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read protected variable: onhashchange." I have submitted fix to them:
https://github.com/asual/jquery-address/pull/130

Comment: thanks! actually i saw your fix, but just didn't have time to test it.